# Visual Studio 2013 incorrect variable value when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

I have a problem with Visual Studio 2013. Its showing incorrect value.

There are two variable with same name but they are in different scopes. [image]

Comment: Did you try to rename the second variable? I understand they have different scopes, but i am just curious if it could be a bug in VS because of the same name.

Comment: is your code running on different threads

Comment: Side note - Is it just me or is this is all code duplication, where all you really want to know is which detail to fill? You could refactor this into a single method and call it twice.

Comment: @Amit Why does it matter if this is multi-threaded? `dbItem` is a local variable.

Comment: @Amit No, Its not multi-thread. Even it was a multithread app, variables are in same thread.

Comment: @Yuval , Yes I know. Its duplicate code. But this is not my question :) .

Answer (score 0):

First, I would rename the second variable, it will help you in debugging this issue if you can differentiate it. Also, I have come across this type of issue myself, and it *always* turns out that another operation has changed the value. Your variable is a class, and as such as operations are performed with it, there is always a chance that somewhere, something changes it.
I would check every place where that variable is touched (passed around) and see if there is something you missed.

Good Luck.

Answer (score -2):

I see the same thing. Running in visual studio and then in turn run from powershell prompt where i write-debug the value and I see what I expect in the write statement but not in debug.

```
#Add this, and then run the same file in the powershell prompt 

"%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" "FILENAME"

#In the code
Write-Debug($myvariable)
```